# Is it possible to generate a map from a list of points with distance?

Tags: algorithm, maps, path-finding, decision-tree

I have got a list of nodes and each node has got a weight. This weight represents the distance from one node to another and it is directed.
Is it possible to generate a map similar to a game graph where each of these nodes contains a 2D or 3D position (or maybe a multidimensional)?


 
Similar to this map: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElV6e.png

 
Or this but including positions: http://www.nature.com/srep/2012/120608/srep00444/images/srep00444-f8.jpg


My data set will be similar to this:

Node   Cost   ConnectsTo 
A            1            B, C          
 
B            2            D             
 
C            3            E             
D            4            E             
E            5

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327796/embedding-graph-in-euclidean-space

The types of graphs you are asking about are known as [Euclidean Graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclideanGraph.html).  See here for [Euclidean MST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree)

Comment: It's a bit odd that the weight is associated with a vertex and not an edge. An obstruction to representing the graph by Euclidean distances is that there is a cycle that violates the triangle inequality, where one edge is larger than the lengths of the other edges put together. This can be as simple as that the weight of the edge from A to B is not the same as the weight of the opposite edge.